# Why can't I find the json data from others' Wordpress site by adding /wp-json/wp/v2/posts?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

Now I'm trying to create a Wordpress plugin using REST API to collect the blog post content. I'm trying to add "/wp-json/wp/v2/posts" at the end of people's Wordpress website to load the json data of their post properties. But some of the sites work, some of them don't. Why does that happen?

The example:
https://profesorjitaruionel.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts (this one works)
https://raptorpersecutionuk.org/wp-json/wp/v2/posts (this does not)

If that is not the way to know the json data of the site's post properties, can someone tell me the correct way to do that? Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: There are many plugins that exist to disable the API. Basically, if they're not using it many responsible administrators will turn it off to stop people doing things that they don't want them to do... like use it to scrape all the content.

Answer (score 0):

That second website is a `wordpress.com` website, and not the open source version. Those can be targeted via the [wordpress.com API](https://developer.wordpress.com/docs/api/1.1/get/sites/%24site/posts/) and by doing that for your example the endpoint would be https://public-api.wordpress.com/rest/v1.1/sites/raptorpersecutionuk.org/posts/

Answer (score 0):

You have to create 2 plugins one for receiver side and second for sender site